# My code doesn't recognize jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, typescript, powerbi

I want to get the value inside a specific `<div>` that my code auto generate but when I use jQuery syntax it seems like that syntax does not recognize id tagged div.

HTML code is hold inside Variable, below is one `<div>` cover by td tag that I want to get the data inside this `<div>`! The string interpolation (`${count}`) is correct - I have tested it by put it inside `<div></div>` and its output is correct which is increase from 1 to the n base on my for loop above to initialize `<div>`.

```
<td><div id='${count}' contenteditable='true'>editable</div></td>
```

```js
$("#1").keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
     // I don't know how get this text inside it too :( 
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me please?!

Comment: When you say HTML code is held in a variable does that mean you don't add it to the page DOM?

Comment: @apokryfos I'm not sure! Is this line mean have already added to page DOM:
this.target.innerHTML = varContainHtmlCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword to reference the contenteditable `div` element which raised the event. From there you can use `html()` to get its contents.

Also note that your logic implies that the `div` is dynamically appended to the DOM. As such you will need to use a delegated event handler, as the element doesn't exist when the page loads. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', '#1', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    var content = $(this).html();
    console.log(content);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="1" contenteditable="true">editable</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you save my day! But can you explain me about using delegate event handler which you mention above please! @Rory McCrossan

Comment: No problem, glad to help. A standard event handler requires the element to exist in the DOM when the JS runs. A delegated event handler instead hooks to the selector you provide at any point it becomes available in the DOM, even in the future. For more detail see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for . `kepress` event is intended for `input` .

```js
var count = 1;

var HTML = '<input id=' + count + ' contenteditable="true" placeholder="Press Enter">';

$(".test").html(HTML)

$("#1").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    alert(1)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But it seems your code is not worked in my case! I combined Typescript with jQuery and the library of jQuery install by npm, the line: $(".test).html(HTML) - can you explain me what is this for? Also I have followed with your instruction too by adding this single line too (But in my case class name "test" is inside <table class="test"> tag which cover outside all my <div id=${count}> and nothing happen then :( @Obito Uchiha